# Recycler view with multiple layout items duplicate radio buttons on scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

`RecyclerView` containing multiple layouts such as one row containing `Edittext`, `radioButtons` another row containing `checkbox` etc

Now when I input in first edit text and scroll the list then same inputed value gets copied in the last edit text visible on the screen.

Also if there are two radio buttons visible say radio1 and radio 2 then on scroll this becomes
radio1
radio2
radio1
radio2
i.e. radio1 and radio 2 are duplicated on scroll.

Can any one suggest some solution for the same?

> Code for dynamic Edit Text

```
private void configureViewHolderText(final ViewHolderText holderText, final int position) {
    if (questionsArrayList != null && questionsArrayList.size() > 0) {

        String hint = questionsArrayList.get(position).getHelperText();
        int characterLength = questionsArrayList.get(position).getCharLimit();
        boolean isQuestionRequired = questionsArrayList.get(position).isRequired();


        if (isQuestionRequired) {
            holderText.getTv_dynamic_star().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        holderText.getTv_dynamic_text_view().setText(questionsArrayList.get(position).getQuestionText());

        if (characterLength > 0) {
            holderText.getEt_dynamic_edit_text().setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(characterLength)});
        }


        if (hint != null && hint.equals("null") == false && hint.equals("") == false) {
            holderText.getEt_dynamic_edit_text().setHint(hint);
        } else {
            holderText.getEt_dynamic_edit_text().setHint("Enter Answer");
        }


        holderText.getEt_dynamic_edit_text().addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                editTextInput = holderText.getEt_dynamic_edit_text().getText().toString();
              //  SubmitAnswerRequest submitAnswerRequest = new SubmitAnswerRequest();
              //  SubmitAnswerRequest.answers answers = submitAnswerRequest.new answers();

               // hashAnswerInput.put(questionsArrayList.get(position).get_id(), editTextInput);
                /*hashQuestionText.put(questionsArrayList.get(position).get_id(), questionsArrayList.get(position).getQuestionText()) ;
                hashQuestionId.put(questionsArrayList.get(position).get_id(), questionsArrayList.get(position).get_id()) ;
                hashAnswerType.put(questionsArrayList.get(position).get_id(), questionsArrayList.get(position).getAnswerType());*/

               /* for(Map.Entry map  :  hashAnswerInput.entrySet() )
                {
                    dynamicEditTextAnswer = String.valueOf(map.getValue());
                    //answers.setAnswerText(inputAnswer);
                }*/

                /*if(dynamicEditTextAnswer!= null)
                {*/
                    SubmitAnswerRequest submitAnswerRequest = new SubmitAnswerRequest();
                    SubmitAnswerRequest.answers answers = submitAnswerRequest.new answers();
                    answers.setQuestionText(questionsArrayList.get(position).getQuestionText());
                    answers.setQuestionId(questionsArrayList.get(position).get_id());
                    answers.setAnswerText(editTextInput);
                    answers.setAnswerType(questionsArrayList.get(position).getAnswerType());
                    answersArrayList.put(questionsArrayList.get(position).get_id(),answers);
              /*  }*/






                /*for(Map.Entry map  :  hashQuestionText.entrySet() )
                {
                    String inputAnswer = String.valueOf(map.getValue());
                    answers.setQuestionText(inputAnswer);
                }

                for(Map.Entry map  :  hashQuestionId.entrySet() )
                {
                    String inputAnswer = String.valueOf(map.getValue());
                    answers.setQuestionId(inputAnswer);
                }

                for(Map.Entry map  :  hashAnswerType.entrySet() )
                {
                    String inputAnswer = String.valueOf(map.getValue());
                    answers.setAnswerType(inputAnswer);
                }*/


               // SubmitAnswerRequest submitAnswerRequest = new SubmitAnswerRequest();
               // SubmitAnswerRequest.answers answers = submitAnswerRequest.new answers();
               // answers.setQuestionText(questionsArrayList.get(position).getQuestionText());
               // answers.setQuestionId(questionsArrayList.get(position).get_id());
               // answers.setAnswerText(editTextInput);
              //  answers.setAnswerType(questionsArrayList.get(position).getAnswerType());
              //  answersArrayList.add(answers);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });



    }

}
```

> Code for dynamic radio button

```
private void configureViewHolderRadioGroup(final ViewHolderRadioGroup holderRadioGroup, final int position) {
    if (questionsArrayList != null && questionsArrayList.size() > 0) {
        ArrayList<String> radioOptionsList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int j = 0; j < questionsArrayList.get(position).getOptions().size(); j++) {
            String radioItemName = questionsArrayList.get(position).getOptions().get(j).getOptionText();
            radioOptionsList.add(radioItemName);


        }

        holderRadioGroup.getTv_dynamic_text_view().setText(questionsArrayList.get(position).getQuestionText());

        boolean isQuestionRequired = questionsArrayList.get(position).isRequired();

        if (isQuestionRequired) {
            holderRadioGroup.getTv_dynamic_star().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        int totalCount = questionsArrayList.get(position).getOptions().size();
        final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[totalCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) {
            rb[i] = new RadioButton(context);
            rb[i].setText(radioOptionsList.get(i));
            rb[i].setId(i);
            holderRadioGroup.getRg_dynamic_radio_group().addView(rb[i]); //the RadioButtons are added to the radioGroup instead of the layout


            holderRadioGroup.getRg_dynamic_radio_group().setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
                        RadioButton rg = (RadioButton) group.getChildAt(i);
                        if (rg.getId() == checkedId) {
                            radioInput = rg.getText().toString();


                            Toast.makeText(context, radioInput, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            SubmitAnswerRequest submitAnswerRequest = new SubmitAnswerRequest();
                            SubmitAnswerRequest.answers answers = submitAnswerRequest.new answers();
                            answers.setQuestionText(questionsArrayList.get(position).getQuestionText());
                            answers.setQuestionId(questionsArrayList.get(position).get_id());
                            answers.setAnswerText(radioInput);
                            answers.setAnswerType(questionsArrayList.get(position).getAnswerType());
                           // answersArrayList.add(answers);
                            answersArrayList.put(questionsArrayList.get(position).get_id(),answers);


                            ArrayList<String> relatedQuestionsId = new ArrayList<String>();
                            relatedQuestionsId = questionsArrayList.get(position).getOptions().get(i).getRelatedQuestionIds();

                            if (relatedQuestionsId != null && relatedQuestionsId.size() > 0) {

                                for (int k = 0; k < relatedQuestionsId.size(); k++) {
                                    ((LinearLayout) holderRadioGroup.getLl_parent_radio_child()).removeAllViews();
                                    getRadioChildQuestions(relatedQuestionsId, holderRadioGroup, k);
                                }

                            }


                            return;
                        }
                        else if(rg.getId() != checkedId) {
                            ArrayList<String> relatedQuestionsId = new ArrayList<String>();
                                /*for (int j = 0; j < questionsArrayList.get(position).getOptions().size(); j++) {*/
                            relatedQuestionsId = questionsArrayList.get(position).getOptions().get(i).getRelatedQuestionIds();

                            if (relatedQuestionsId != null && relatedQuestionsId.size() > 0) {

                                for (int k = 0; k < relatedQuestionsId.size(); k++) {

                                    ((LinearLayout) holderRadioGroup.getLl_parent_radio_child()).removeAllViews();
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: ok let me post it

Answer (score 2):

The recycler view reuses your view holders instances. 
So if you are scrolling and a layout is leaving the screen at the top, it gets reused, when the same layout should be used for a new item at the bottom.

You need to reset all dynamic attribues in the `onBindViewHolder`-method.

For a better understanding set two debug points inside your recycler view adapter:
One inside the `onCreateViewHolder`-method and one inside the `onBindViewHolder`-method.

**EDIT:**
A sample for a working Recycler View Adapter can be found here: https://github.com/olLenz/Movies-with-Kotlin/blob/master/base/src/main/java/com/lenz/oliver/movieswithkotlin/ui/home/HomeAdapter.kt

The `onCreateViewHolder`-method creates a new instance of the ViewHolder. 
The `onBindViewHolder`-method just calls the bind-method on a created ViewHolder instance. This bind-method sets all dynamic information to the given layout on every call.

Comment: Thank you for replying, can you please add some sample code for resetting dynamic attributes in onBindViewHolder - method.

Comment: I update my answer. The sample is written in Kotlin, but the concept should be understandable.